# Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New() VB .NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I use MySqlBackup.NET_2.0.9.2 to backup a MySQL database.
I use this code:

```
Private Sub cmdExportBazaDate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExportBazaDate.Click

    Dim constring As String = Parametriiconexiune
    Dim zi As String = data
    Dim file As String = cale_salvari + data + "_baza" + ".sql"

    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    conn = New MySqlConnection(constring)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    cmd = New MySqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Dim mb As MySqlBackup
    mb = New MySqlBackup(cmd)
    mb.ExportToFile(file)
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

I get the error:
Too many arguments to 'Public Sub New()'

For this line:
mb = New MySqlBackup(cmd)

How to fix please to bypass the error.

Comment: `MySqlBackup` seems like a custom class you wrote, and the constructor doesn't accept a string. Please show us the constructors of the `MySqlBackup` class.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt it is a NuGet package.  It works fine for me ( `Using mySB As New MySqlBackup(cmd)` ), make sure you are working with the version you think you are and that the references and package are there

Comment: ya this works fine for me. here is reference link https://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Vezi ca nu  e inclus in proiect .. ceva de genul

Comment: vezi ce mai gaseti util pe aicvi https://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MySqlBackup.NET/MySqlBackup/MySqlBackup.cs

Comment: The problem was from MySqlConnector - version must be 6.9.7.0 and i have 6.9.6.0.